# getting clipboard content as a string variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, clipboard

Trying to get clipboard content as a string variable (for example page url is copied);

The code below returns `undefined` in console.

```js
function get_clip(){
 navigator.clipboard.readText().then(text => {return text;})
 .catch(err => {console.error('Failed to read clipboard contents: ', err);});
}

var str = get_clip();
console.log(str);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't get the value of clipboard like this for 2 reasons :

1. your function is asynchronus so when you call your function there is
   no `return` called, your value is equal to undefined. You can use
   callBack function passed in params of `get_clip` func to do your job
   with your result.
2. you can't call clipboard programmatically for security reason
   navigator don't allow you to access clipboard without user action
   with web page. That why only with click of button you have access to user clipboard.

```js
function get_clip(callBack) {
  navigator.clipboard.readText()
    .then(text => {
      callBack(text);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.error('Failed to read clipboard contents: ', err);
    });
}


let callback = function(str) {
  console.log(str);
};

document.querySelector('#showClipboard').addEventListener('click', function() {
  get_clip(callback);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="showClipboard">click me to show clipboard</button>
```

Answer (score 4):

That is because it takes time to execute `get_clip()`, it takes time to read the clipboard (imagine you could have a huge amount of text in the clipboard), and the JavaScript engine does not stop but instead executes the next line and logs 'undefined'.

Asynchronous JavaScript: (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Introducing)

---

So, what you can do is tell `get_clip()` what to do when is done reading the clipboard. You can say to `get_clip()`, execute this function `aCallback` with something like this:

```js
var str = get_clip(aCallback);
```

---

Try this code:

```js
function get_clip(callback) {
    navigator.clipboard.readText()
        .then(text => { return callback(text); })
        .catch(err => {
            console.error('Failed to read clipboard contents: ', err);
        });
}

var str = get_clip(aCallback);

function aCallback(text) {
    console.log(text);
}
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: navigator.clipboard.readText is not a function
    get_clip

Comment: @DamodarDas Try console.log(navigator) and see if you have something.

Answer (score 2):

Just to give a different form of answer including the `async` function:

```
function get_clip(){

    navigator.clipboard.readText()
    .then(text => {
        console.log('Pasted content: ', text);
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.error('Failed to read clipboard contents: ', err);
    });

}

get_clip();
```

And using `async` function:

```
async function get_clip(){
    try {
        return navigator.clipboard.readText();
    } catch (err) {
        console.error('Failed to read clipboard contents: ', err);
    }
}

const text = await get_clip();
console.log('Pasted content: ', text);
```

Comment: You would have to use `await` to get `str`